# Reading and writing a text value using selenium and pandas when the html element has no definite id

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium-webdriver

I am working on creating a program that would read a list of aircraft registrations from an excel file and return the aircraft type codes.

My source of information is FlightRadar24. (example - https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/n502dn)
I tried inspecting the elements on the page to find the correct class id to invoke and found the id to be listed as "details" When I run my code, it extracts the aircraft name with the class id/name details, instead of the type code.
[See here for the example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ7Ch.png)
I then changed my approach to using XPath to seek the correct text but with the xpath it prints out
(For Xpath, i used a browser add on to find the exact xpath for the element, fairly confident that it is correct.)
It gives no output. What would you suggest in this particular instance when extracting values without a definite id ?

```
for i in list_regs:

        driver.get('https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/'+i)
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)

        load = 0

        while load==0:

            try:
                element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div/section/section[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/span")
                print('element') #Printing to terminal to see if the right value is returned.
```

Comment: Why are you printing the string `'element'` and not the variable: `print('element')`

Comment: Yes, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably change your xpath expression to:

```
//label[.="TYPE CODE"]/following-sibling::span[@class="details"]
```

and

```
print('element')
```

to

```
print(element)
```

Edit:
This works for me:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[.="TYPE CODE"]/following-sibling::span[@class="details"]')
print(element.text)
```

Output:

```
A359
```

Comment: Hello @JackFleeting ! Thank you for your help. I have corrected the element error. As for the xpath expression, it shows me a syntax error when i try to build it.

Comment: Thank you Jack. Your answer showed me a totally different way of using xpath. Appreciate it !